# How to filter combinations of two columns by cominations of two columns in linux

Tags: bash, filtering

I have a dataset where each individual is identified by combination of two columns (column1=familynumber, column2= individualnumber) and I have to remove individuals (rows) from this dataset, but again, the list of individuals to remove is given in the same format.

Data set example:

```
             F2              15            0
             F2              17            0
             F3              15            0
             F4              17            0
             F4              25            0
             F6              32            0
             F6              38            0
```

list to remove(patterns to filter from) example:

```
F2  15
F4  17
F6  32
```

output example

```
             F2              17            0
             F3              15            0
             F4              25            0
             F6              38            0
```

I know grep has this function to use combination of patterns `'pattern1.*pattern2'` (AND) but I would also need this to function on 2 lists of patterns (either a file with 2 columns or 2 files with one column each `-f`), I have tried both with no luck. Either way I dont know how to combine these two features properly and I am out of ideas.
I would take any suggestions, Thank you

this is the code that I have tried so far

```
egrep -f rejected.i -v dataset.exm
```

where `rejected.i` is the file containing both columns of the pattern to filter

and

```
grep -e  -v -f i.rej1 grep -e -v -f i.rej2 dataset.exm
```

where i.rej1 and i.rej2 are the first and second columns, respectively, of the patterns to filter.

I hope it is clear enough.
thank you again

Comment: Not clear, could you please elaborate it more by mentioning with expected sample output too in your post.

Comment: For example, My dataset wiil contain individuals F1 15 , and F2 15, I need to remove the F2 15 without removing the F1 15.

Comment: @EstebanLopera It's best to include in your question what the desired output should look like :)

Comment: @EstebanLopera, you could add 3 simple things, 1- sample input, 2- sample output and 3rd- your efforts to solve your problem in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: check `uniq -w N` command

Comment: Probably you can solve your problem by using `join` to get the elements on a list that are not in the other list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join on two text files](/questions/13272717/inner-join-on-two-text-files). This is not a straight inner join but the same approach should work. You can probably find better duplciates. Anyway, this is a very common FAQ.

Comment: hey @tripleee, This question was succesfully answered. I would appreciate if you don't mark my other questions as duplicates without reading. If you don't want to read them i'ts fine, but don't just assume I am asking the same question over and over again, y0our are hidnering my advance. Thank you.

Comment: I could have closed this one but I granted you the benefit of the doubt. The comment above is just a comment; though you should perhaps spend some time examining the nominated duplicate and the vast mass of related existing questions.

Comment: did you notice that the solution is not even near your proposal?. If your are to lazy to properly read a question please don't answer. the question you just marked as duplicate was also a completely different problem from this.

Comment: That's mainly because the answer is a poor reimplementation of the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat i.rej1
F2
F4
F6
$ cat i.rej2
15
17
32
```

## Create correct pattern file

You can create a pattern file using `paste` and replacing tabs with regex for *one or more spaces*

```
$ paste i.rej1 i.rej2 | sed 's/\t/\\s+/'
F2\s+15
F4\s+17
F6\s+32
```

Using [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), your grep would read

```
$ grep -Evf <(paste i.rej1 i.rej2 | sed 's/\t/\\s+/') input 
             F2              17            0
             F3              15            0
             F4              25            0
             F6              38            0
```

`paste i.rej1 i.rej2 | sed 's/\t/\\s+/' | grep -Evf- input` would do the same.

Comment: Thank you. to be honest, I still don't understand much about the sed command, nor the process substitution.  But this certainly solved the issue.